# Simple menu selection and bubbling working unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I have a simple text menu made of ul and li, and a nested sublist inside. The design calls for the top-level items to slide open/closed the contained ul-li submenu. Clicking on submenu items would just bold them.

Here's my markup and script:

```
    <ul id="appNavigationMainMenu">
    <li id="appOperate" class="selected" >
        <p id="mainitem1">Operate</p>
        <ul id="appOperateSubmenu">
            <li id="appOperateSub1">
                <p>Alerts</p>
            </li>
            <li id="appOperateSub2">
                <p>Availability</p>
            </li>
            <li id="appOperateSub3">
                <p>Performance</p>
            </li>
            <li id="appOperateSub4">
                <p>Reliability</p>
            </li>
            <li id="appOperateSub5">
                <p>Resource Utilization</p>
            </li>
            <li id="appOperateSub6">
                <p>Workloads</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="appAnalyze" class="">
        <p id="mainitem2">Analyze</p>
        <ul id="appAnalyzeSubmenu">
            <li id="appAnalyzeSub1">
                <p>AnalyzeSub1</p>
            </li>
            <li id="appAnalyzeSub2">
                <p>AnalyzeSub2</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

        $(document).ready(function () {

        //var menuitem = $("#appNavigationMainMenu + li");
        var menuitem = $("#appOperate, #appAnalyze");

        $(menuitem).click(function (e) {
            alert(e.target);
            $(menuitem).removeClass("selected");
            $(menuitem).find("ul").slideUp(250);
            $(this).addClass("selected");

            $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(250);
            e.stopPropagation;

        });

        $("#appOperateSubmenu > li").click(function (e) {
            $("#appOperateSubmenu > li").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            e.stopPropagation;
        });

        // start with Operate open
        $("#appOperate").find("ul").show();

    });
```

(I'm sure this markup is terrible in some way, but I'm just trying to get a simple prototype going.)

When the menu is open and I click a submenu item, the parent menu opens/closes. I think the problem is event propagation but `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation` don't work.

Here's a fiddle: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/hEDjh/)

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't touch your markup, but I have fixed the javascript. I believe it is doing what you want now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//a more specific selector so we don't trigger the menu closing when clicking sub-items        
var menuitem = $("#appNavigationMainMenu li p");
//selector for submenus
var submenuitem = $("#appNavigationMainMenu li ul li");

//only need toggle - it handles open and close
$(menuitem).click(function (e) {
    //select the next ul under the <p> to expand/contract
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(250); //show
});

$(submenuitem).click(function(e){
    //un-bold any lis that are bold "selected" 
    $('#appNavigationMainMenu').find("li").css("font-weight", "normal");
    //make our current selection bold
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
});

//start with analyze closed, you can change this when you add more sub menus
$('#appAnalyze ul').hide()
});​
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hEDjh/14/

Note: you can handle the bolding and unbolding with removeClass and addClass, I just didn't feel like changing the css.

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't quite what I wanted, but your better selectors let me get there.